# Why is moving objects, on the Z Plane, so unprecise?

Tags: transforms

When I look through the camera and try to move objects in the scene while constraining their movement to the Z-Plane (<kbd>G</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>), the tiniest movements throw them from one side to the other.

But this only happens sometimes.

Other times I can move them precise and without a problem, so surely I must have hit a button that does that.

Answer (score 8):

When translating constrained to a plane, the mouse motion is translated relative to that plane. This is fine when the 'view' is relatively distant to the plane but if the view is close to the plane of motion then any small movement can be drastically amplified (for example, moving the mouse slightly 'up' can result in the object disappearing into the distance).

To test this, simply open the default scene. Select the cube and <kbd>G</kbd> to grab it, then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>. Note that when you move the mouse the motion of the cube closely matches. Cancel the movement by pressing <kbd>Escape</kbd> so the cube returns to the centre.

Now move the view so that you are close to the plane of the grid like so :

[image: view close to plane]

Now repeat the above keystrokes to grab the cube constrained to the plane. Move the mouse up/down and see how it now behaves - it will shoot off into the distance as the mouse moves up. The motion is relative to the plane - since the plane is at a very shallow angle in the view, small vertical motions correspond to large changes in distance.

To avoid this issue simply ensure the view point is not close to the plane of motion.

Comment: My problem is not with the general concept. Problem is that  i cant move the mouse at all without it shooting off. I have worked in the same scene, through the same camera, with the same objects before and it worked fine.

Comment: @JensClar If it's not the same as described then perhaps you could provide more info - it's very difficult to diagnose without seeing it happen so if you could capture an animated gif or video or a blend file that shows the problem and edit it into your question that would be useful.

Comment: Now its back to normal. I'll either edit this question when it happens within the next days again, or i'll have to ask a new, more precise question with additional info and a .blend once this one gets burried under the new submissions.

Answer (score 3):

You can also try holding down shift as you move the object it slows down the movement speed and snap increments

Answer (score 0):

I know that if your object is parented to something else, it can make it harder to move precisely (depending on your situation), but you can also type in numerical values for how far you want it to go. Select your object, push "g" to grab, push "z" to constrain to z plane, and then a number that you can change to your liking. Sometimes that works better for me than to use my mouse to drag the object.